# Install dependencies issue after running setup.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, setup.py

I downloaded a github repository and run the python setup.py file whitin it running `$python setup.py` command from linux terminal but i got the following error

```
[setup.py] Running [sudo apt-get -y install libjsoncpp-dev postgresql jq python-psycopg2 python-sqlalchemy socat libpq-dev cmake docker.io bc python-pexpect python-psutil python-lockfile genisoimage inotify-tools build-essential python-pip libprotobuf-c0-dev libodb-pgsql-2.4 libfdt-dev] . . . 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-psycopg2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package python-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python3-pip

E: Package 'python-psycopg2' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python-pip' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libprotobuf-c0-dev

[setup.py] [sudo apt-get -y install libjsoncpp-dev postgresql jq python-psycopg2 python-sqlalchemy socat libpq-dev cmake docker.io bc python-pexpect python-psutil python-lockfile genisoimage inotify-tools build-essential python-pip libprotobuf-c0-dev libodb-pgsql-2.4 libfdt-dev] cmd did not execute properly.
```

Trying to fix the error one by one, first i tried to install python-psycopg2 using `pip install psycopg2` and the output is:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in 'path'
```

I also tried to run python -m pip install psycopg2 but the output did not change. So i downloaded the source (from https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/#files) and using the setup.py i got:

```
    File "setup.py", line 117
        f"Unable to find 'pg_config' file in '{self.pg_config_exe}'")
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can i fix all the errors ? is it a python 2.7 issue ?

Comment: Try pip3 install psycopg2

Comment: @DSteman Definitely, and it worked but when i run python2 setup.py again i always got the same error

Comment: why are you using python2 and not python3?

Comment: @DSteman The framework i downloaded from github is about 3 years ago and it seems to not support python3

Comment: I see. If you try this: pip install psycopg2-binary

Comment: @DSteman i tried it too and the output : `DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2-binary in path.`

Comment: So it seems to be impossible then. What kinda framework is it? There should be a modern solution for the problem you’re facing

Comment: @DStemanI This is the github repository https://github.com/panda-re/lava

Comment: I guess this is not possible because dependencies don't support python2 anymore

Comment: @DSteman i think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependencies are not supported for python 2, so it's impossible to use the module described in the comments.